# Cannot get to Django root url (r'^$') after deploying to Elastic Beanstalk, all other routes work

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When deploying a django project to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I am able to get to all of my urlpatterns except the root pattern (*i.e.* what should map to sitename-staging.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com). The page never loads anything and eventually chrome shows ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.
Note that I am able to get to all my other routes (*i.e.* sitename-staging.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/members, /admin, etc) and all the static files are on S3 and seem to be working.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/home.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^users/', include('sitename.users.urls', namespace='users')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^members/', include('sitename.members.urls', namespace='members')),
    url(r'^contact/', include('sitename.contact.urls', namespace='contact')),
    url(r'^settings/', include('sitename.sitesettings.urls', namespace='settings')),
    url(r'^history/$', views.flatpage, {'url': '/history/'}, name='history'),
    url(settings.ADMIN_URL, include(admin.site.urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

There are no errors during deployment and the health shows ok on the dashboard. I am able to get to my root route as expected when running locally or with docker.

This isn't an issue with the template I am trying to route to as I can change the route and it will load correctly at the new route:
ex: `url(r'^test$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/home.html'), name='home'),`
I have tried moving the ^$ route up and down above the other named routes but that doesn't seem to work

Nothing is sticking out in the logs, but it seems as if the request never even gets to Apache from what I can understand as I am not getting back a 4xx or 5xx error and there isn't an entry that I tried to view the page in /var/log/httpd/access_log

**/opt/python/log/supervisord.log**:

```
2017-07-30 00:52:14,064 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2017-07-30 00:52:14,085 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-07-30 00:52:14,085 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2017-07-30 00:52:14,085 INFO supervisord started with pid 3022
2017-07-30 00:52:15,088 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 3105
2017-07-30 00:52:16,325 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

**/var/log/httpd/error_log**:

```
[Sun Jul 30 00:52:15.336938 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3105] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 30 00:52:15.338467 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3105] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 30 00:52:15.338486 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3105] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

**/var/log/httpd/access_log**:

These four lines show up when I start the instance, it seems that they are trying to check '/' and getting a 404 but not sure. I have made sure 127.0.0.1 is in the ALLOWED HOSTS. See that there is a successful request to the /history route at the end

```
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [30/Jul/2017:02:06:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 4705 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [30/Jul/2017:02:06:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 4705 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [30/Jul/2017:02:06:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 4705 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [30/Jul/2017:02:06:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 4705 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36"
<my_ip_address> (-) - - [30/Jul/2017:01:43:34 +0000] "GET /a HTTP/1.1" 200 5871 "http://sitename-staging.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/history/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36"
```

**/var/log/eb-activity.log**

This looks odd but the are not any other errors and the other routes are working

```
[2017-07-30T02:06:16.844Z] INFO  [25864] - [Configuration update app-ee500-170729_204230@6/ConfigDeployStage1/ConfigDeployEnactHook/01flip.py] : Completed activity. Result:
  httpd: stopped
  httpd: started
  httpd                            RUNNING   pid 25973, uptime 0:00:03
2017-07-30 02:06:16,750 INFO     Apache is running, but root page is not responding in 3 seconds.
```

Additional Project Information:

- project structure similar to what cookiecutter-django produces
- doesn't have this problem running locally or on docker (gunicorn/nginx)
- static files on s3
- Database on RDS and migrated successfully
- Python 3.4
- Following [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) to convert my project elastic beanstalk
- ALLOWED_HOSTS contains the elastic beanstalk url, EC2 Public IP, localhost, 127.0.0.1

Comment: Instead of following realpython tutorial see if the aws one has something different that got missed?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Comment: I followed that tutorial and was able to get the default hello world page to show up on elastic beanstalk. However, when I try to apply the same thing to a little bit more complex site I am getting this error, so I would guess it is something with my settings but not sure where to look

Comment: Try and reducing the number of rules in urls.py and limit them to 2 and 3 and post your observations

Comment: I reduced the routes all the way down to one and still had this issue. I am positive that this is now some sort of configuration/permission issue with AWS/elastic beanstalk, not the django routes. I just found that I can get to the root url of my site and everything works as expected with using the EC2 Elastic IP address and the Elastic IP Public DNS address, but the root route at the elastic beanstalk url seems to be having an issue

Comment: Yes it may be an AWS issue then. Better open it at some AWS forum?

Comment: Have you resolved it? Same issue for me